# upgraded Xcode to 4.5.2 from 4.3.2 and install Simulator 5.0 or 5.1

Tags: xcode, simulator

I upgraded Xcode to 4.5.2 from 4.3.2 and install Simulator 5.0 or 5.1  but it tips
"**Failed to mount file://localhost/Users/admin/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/Xcode.SDK.iPhoneSimulator.5.1-5.1.dmg at file://localhost/var/folders/sw/qht9m6ln7353v5mbfyvhtmf00000gn/T/attached-image-6fdc393a2528f4e65d994f841bfb0d76b998b7e3/: not recognized"**,  how can I do,thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a work around for this. I am currently using Xcode 4.5 so I am sure it works for 4.5.2 as well.
I found the URL's for downloads in the .dvtdownloadabelindex file located in

```
Users/<user>/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/
```

I copied the file to my Desktop and renamed it to .plist. Looking through some of the I found two URLs to download the simulators (Root/downloadables/Item 9/ for iPhoneSimulator 5.0 and Root/downloadables/Item 17/ for iPhoneSimulator 5.1).  Not sure if I am allowed to post the direct URLs due to Apple TOS and whatnot.

I downloaded the two simulators, installed what was in the .dmg. It made a folder in the root of my drive called Platforms. I then copied

```
/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk
```

to

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk
```

Restart Xcode (or in my case, MonoTouch), go into Xcode preferences and to the tab you would normally download them from, click install and this will get rid of the "iOS Simulator could not find the SDK. The SDK may need to be reinstalled." error that you would normally get.

You now have access to the iPhone/iPad iOS 5.0 Simulators. I have only done this for the 5.0 simulator not 5.1, but I am sure it will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

- Delete *.dvtdownloadableindex file
- Restart Xcode
- Install simulators